# How to generate script lists in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

IN SQL Server there is a tasks feature and then you can 'generate scripts' which is useful for things like views and stored procedures, or more.

In Oracle, can I generate such a copy of Views? How is this done? I am using PL SQL.

I am trying to update my Oracle database on my laptop. REcently many new views and stored procedures were added to the database I am working on at job. I also work from laptop for development.

Rather than backup the entire database, if I can just copy these views and sp's would be far easier.

Comment: Elaborate a little please. Provide an example of what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: if you use a tool like TOAD, then you can view an object (Procedure, Function, Table, Index, etc.) and say - 'see SQL script' which you can then save off somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are probably looking for the [`DBMS_METADATA` package and the `GET_xxx` functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019414) within that package.  This is what tools like SQL Developer and other GUIs will call to generate the DDL for a particular object.

So, for example, if you wanted to get the DDL for the `EMP` table in the `SCOTT` schema in SQL (or PL/SQL), you can

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT' )
  2*   from dual
SQL> /

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','EMP','SCOTT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0),
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10),
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        "MGR" NUMBER(4,0),
        "HIREDATE" DATE,
        "SAL" NUMBER(7,2),
        "COMM" NUMBER(7,2),
        "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0),
         CONSTRAINT "PK_EMP" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DE
FAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
  ALTER INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP"  UNUSABLE ENABLE,
         CONSTRAINT "FK_DEPTNO" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTNO")
          REFERENCES "SCOTT"."DEPT" ("DEPTNO") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DE
FAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
  CACHE
```